# How to have css applied to an inline list before it is shown with jquery .show

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I am trying to create a row of 'cells' (just an image of a black square or a white square, depending on its id).  The problem is that when the button is clicked, the 'row' list is generated and shown to the user for a brief period of time without the css applied, then the css is applied and it is displayed correctly.  Is there any way to do this the other way around, to have the css applied, then the table shown?

Css

```
    ol, li { display: inline; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; list-style: none; }
    img { margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; }
```

Jquery

```
            $('#generateTbl').hide();
        $('#generateBtn').click(function () {
                showCellConfiguration();
        });

        var showCellConfiguration = function () {
            loadCells($('#numOfCells').val());
            $('#generateTbl').show('slow', function () { });
        }

        var loadCells = function (numOfCells) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++) {
                $("#row").append('<li><img id="cellOff" class="buttons" src="off.jpg" /></li>');
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<table id='generateTbl'>
    <tr><td><ol id="row"></ol></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if `#generateTbl` is hidden when you click `#generateBtn` then just hide `#generateTbl` before you generate the cells.

Comment: @jcubic I Left out the part about the #generateTbl being hidden upon pageload in my description.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loadCells = function (numOfCells) {
            for (var i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++) {
                var item = $('<li><img id="cellOff" class="buttons" src="off.jpg" /></li>');
                item.ready(function() {
                    $("#row").append($(this));
                });

            }
        }
```

hope works

Comment: I tried this and it still jumped around.  Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

This feels a bit hacking but you could try setting the `position` of the new DOM off the screen for a short interval before adding:

```
var loadCells = function (numOfCells) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++) {
        var newItem = $('<li><img id="cellOff" class="buttons" src="off.jpg" /></li>');

        //set the element off the screen
        newItem.css({ 
            position: absolute,
            left: -9999
        });

        $("#row").append(newItem);

        //now move it back onto the screen after             
        newItem.css({
           position: auto
        });
    }
}
```

You could even add a timeout before you move the element back onto the screen like so:

```
$("#row").append(newItem);

//wait 200 ms before moving the item into position    
window.setTimeout(function() {
    newItem.css({
        position: auto
    });
}, 200);
```

Comment: you're right, it does feel pretty hacky, but if there is no better option this is the route I will take.